# Может ли работать такой код?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var windowRes = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

if (windowRes <= 1024) {
      console.log('hello')
      if(windowRes <= 768) {
        console.log('yes');
      }
    }
```

Есть задумка, но почему то 'yes' не выводится на 768. Есть идеи почему?

Comment: окно сверните до более узкого. И точку с запятой не пропускайте

Comment: Есть верный способ проверить работоспособность кода - запустить его на выполнение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clientWidth = ширина окна, а не экрана.
Соответственно с 1024*768 всё хорошо, там будет примерно 1000, а вот 800х600 уже хуже - вряд ли там будет меньше 768, так что вложенный if не отработает.

Просто посмотрите реальное значение clientWidth в каждом конкретном случае.